# Possible to remove inherited members or prevent inheritance of certain properties/methods?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to "remove" members/methods from a base class, or rather inhibit them for being inherited?

Say I have a class `A` that defines a subscript operator and stores the read/writes of that operator in a map object internally. Then I create `B` which inherits from `A`. Is there any way I can remove the subscript operator from B, or rather, prevent it from being inherited and thus becoming part of B?

Sorry for being so verbose, but to make it clear, I'm not looking for functionality such as the final keyword, where I want to prevent B from overloading something in A. I'm looking to basically say "B, inherit everything from A EXCEPT X". I figure it's not possible and most likely the answer is going to be "fix/improve your design", just thought there was no harm in asking anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the function (or the member) that you want to "delete" private, so the derived class will not be able to "see it". There is no other way of physically removing the function from the derived object (as the derived object contains a copy of the base class, in which your function/member is needed), but making it private guarantees that the derived object has no access to it.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm actually trying to prevent is inheriting the overhead that comes along with these methods. For example, overloading the subscript operator and then storing/retrieving passed args which might be something like boost::any or cdigins::any. I want to avoid this object overhead without having to break the existing inheritance chain.

Comment: +1'd, I figure the answer is that what I want to do precisely isn't possible. If I make the function private, then other external members can't access it either. I guess I'm kinda screwed and may have to reconsider this design.

Comment: As you are deriving from Base, all members of Base are needed in Derived (the constructor of Derived first invokes the constructor of Base, so a full Base object is constructed in Derived). So, with the actual C++ standard, I don't think there is any way of removing methods at the byte-level. You may try however a policy-based design, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design , where each class uses only the methods they need, so you can get rid of the overhead.

Comment: Ahhh, I actually have Andrei Alexandrescu's book on C++, where he goes over this at length. Perhaps I'll pull it out, dust it off and do more than skim over it this time. :) lol